# ¿Como crear un chat-bot Whatsapp que controle comando numéricos?

Tags: php, whatsapp, robots.txt

Mi problema necesito poder procesar información en relación a comandos numéricos, es decir, que mi bot reconozca un numero y lo relacione con una función en especifico. Ejemplo:

- Escriba 1 para recibir un mensaje
- Escriba 2 para no recibir un mensaje

Pero el problema que presento es en el momento de trabajar con las sub opciones o comandos secundarios. Ejemplo:

- Escriba 1 para recibir un mensaje

luego de que el cliente envié este mensaje, el bot debe responder con una serie de opciones. Ejemplo:

- Escriba 1 para recibir un texto
- Escriba 2 para recibir una grabación
- Escriba 3 para recibir una imagen

Esto es lo que busco, pero no encuentro una idea de como poder hacerlo.

La api de WHATSAPP me permite poder crear un [webhook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/webhooks) y obtener los mensajes enviados a mi bot y de esto yo puedo filtrar los que se reconozcan como comando, pero como los distingo, si la opción o comando le pertenece a un **comando principal** o un **comando secundario**, es decir, como diferencio el 1 de recibir un mensaje del 1 de recibir un texto. Ya que no puedo mantener datos a menos que use una base de datos (¿creo?), por la razón de que este bot controlara una gran serie de comandos enviado en **tiempo real** por diferentes usuarios.

Y este webhook puedo usarlo usando el código de una guía de [GITHUB:](https://github.com/chatapi/whatsApp-php)

```
    $client = Client::getInstance([
      'url' => 'your_url',
      'token' => 'your_token'
    ]);

    $data = $client->getWebHook();
```

Pero aun no tengo una idea de como poder diferenciar las opciones numéricas y poder determinar si es principal o secundario el comando solicitado por el usuario. Este es mi problema o inconveniente.

Disculpen mi ignorancia. **Gracias y espero su pronta respuesta.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

efectivamente para poder identificar al emisor del mensaje puedes basarte en el `sender-wa-id` provisto por el webhook de WhatsApp en el campo `from`

**Webhook Entrante:**

```
{"messages":[{
     "from":"1234567890",
     "id":"ABGGhSkIc2B_Ago-sDy5BNm-1gI5",
     "text":{"body":"Hi"},
     "timestamp":"1529381066",
     "type":"text"}
]}
```

Y para poder seguir un flujo de conversación necesitas crear una maquina de estados por id usuario es decir poder seguir un flujo e ir recordando informacion cómo la opción anteriormente seleccionada para este sender.

Ejemplo

```
     #1234567890 -> status 1 -> status 2 -> status 3

Bot pregunta            0          0          0

Usuario 1234567890      2          0          0
   responde  2                         

Si status 1 es 2, 
Responder a usuario.    2          0          0
1234567890 
nuevas opciones

Usuario 1234567890      2          3          0
   responde  3

Si status 1 es 2 y
status 2 es 3, salir    2          3          0
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, como he estado investigando una maquina de estado abarcaría todo eso y habría que usar al menos una librería para aligerar el trabajo. Pero ya que voy ha usar Firebase para guardar algunos datos, usare este mismo para crear un control parecido a una Maquina de Estados.